# View Joint Axes in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, joints

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to view the axes of the joints in rviz, similar to how I can click a checkbox and view the links of my robot? I've figured out how to move the joints using the gui:=true parameter with roslaunch (following the tutorial), but I haven't been able to figure out how to get a simple visualization of their axes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12799/view-joint-axes-in-rviz?/) by [bsklaroff](https://answers.ros.org/users/1710/bsklaroff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-01-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-09-11**:
The answer in #q270701 shows how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `tf` display should show the frames for all your joints.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Instassa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27104/instassa/) on 2017-11-03**:
How do I activate the tf display in rviz?

**Comment by [tc-simulate](https://answers.ros.org/users/45180/tc-simulate/) on 2019-09-15**:
This doesn't answer his question. He specifically asked for JOINTS and not LINKS. The TF display in RVIZ only displays LINKS, not JOINTS.